# Curiously recurring template pattern with variadic templates (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, compile-time, crtp

I have the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Derived>
struct Base {
    void print() const { static_cast<const Derived*>(this)->print(); }  
};

struct Value : public Base<Value> {
    int i;
    void print() const { std::cout << "Value: " << i << std::endl; }
    Value(int j) : i(j) {}
};

void do_variadic_thing() {}

template <typename Derived, typename... Args>
void do_variadic_thing(const Base<Derived>& b, Args... args) {
    std::cout << "Inside do_variadic_thing" << std::endl;
    b.print();
    do_variadic_thing(args...);
}

template <typename Derived>
void do_thing(const Base<Derived>& b) {
    std::cout << "Inside do_thing" << std::endl;
    b.print();
    do_variadic_thing(b, b, b);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    do_thing(Value(1));
}
```

This code uses the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern define a compile-time polymorphic class with a method called `print`.

What I want to do is to run the `print` method from a function with a variable number of arguments (`do_variadic_thing`). The code provided above compiles, but produces a strange output:

```
Inside do_thing
Value: 1
Inside do_variadic_thing
Value: 1
Inside do_variadic_thing
Value: 4206337
Inside do_variadic_thing
Value: 4206337
```

I do not understand why the value printed changes after the second recursive call within `do_variadic_thing`. The argument `b` is replicated 3 times; its type is also the same (i.e `Base<Value>`). It seems that somehow, after the second call, the arguments no longer refer to some valid memory.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass by reference:

```
void do_variadic_thing(const Base<Derived>& b, const Args&... args)
                                                         ^
                                                         here
```

Comment: Thank you. I missed the fact that the reference `b` was actually passed as a _copy_ for the variadic part.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the second/third instances *by value* - consider how the copies are constructed.

Comment: Also note that `Base<Value>` is not `Value`, it does not contain the field `i` (this problem is called "object slicing").

Answer (score 0):

The type of the variable `b` is `Base<Value> const&`, but the object it refers to is of type `Value`. When you copy `b` to replicate it inside `do_thing`, you are *slicing* it; that is, only copying the `Base<Value>` part.